# How to get the value on child_changed event from firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying a lot of ways to do this perfectly but i could not do that. I have a firbase database as shown in this [image: picture]  on child_changed event of this map->marker->0, I have tried to request the value like this

```
    var ref = db.ref("map/markers/0");
      ref.on("child_changed", function() {
      ref.once("value", function(snapshot) {
      // console.log(snapshot.val())
      var data=snapshot.val();
      console.log(data);
      // console.log(data);
    });
```

it gives me the same data 4 times. How can I do this in right way? I wan to get it only once. Thanks in advance.
The result is sth like this

```
    { iconPath: '/images/dashboard/placemarker_lime.png',
      lat: 37.417946,
      lng: -121.97653,
      name: 'Aloft Santa Clara' }
    { iconPath: '/images/dashboard/placemarker_lime.png',
      lat: 37.417946,
      lng: -121.97653,
      name: 'Aloft Santa Clara' }
    { iconPath: '/images/dashboard/placemarker_lime.png',
      lat: 37.417946,
      lng: -121.97653,
      name: 'Aloft Santa Clara' }
    { iconPath: '/images/dashboard/placemarker_lime.png',
      lat: 37.417946,
      lng: -121.97653,
      name: 'Aloft Santa Clara' }
```

Comment: Why did you using ref.once in child_changed just try to remove it and replace ref.on to ref.on("child_changed", function(snapshot) {...}

Comment: @PanupongKongarn i did that previously, it didn't work so i used once. okay I am removing it and putting on.

Comment: @PanupongKongarn When I do this removing ref.on('value') 
var ref = db.ref("map/markers/0");
  ref.on("child_changed", function(snapshot) {
  var data=snapshot.val();
  console.log(data);
}); 
It gives me the result for only once, but it in this form:
/images/dashboard/placemarker_lime.png
37.417946
-121.97653
Aloft Santa Clara

Now is there any way to point to lat, longitute , image and place?

Comment: var data = snapshot.val(); using data["iconPath"], data["lat"], ....

Comment: @PanupongKongarn okay I will try it just now.

Comment: @PanupongKongarn It said undefined on doing this: console.log(data["lat"]);

Comment: Please try to change your ref to db.ref("map/markers");

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160335/discussion-between-panupong-kongarn-and-suz-aann-shrestha).

Comment: Please replace `ref.on("child_changed", function() { ref.once("value", function(snapshot) {` with `ref.on("child_changed", function(snapshot) {`. Also: the data you log looks exactly the same at first glance. What changed?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen  on doing so , I got data only once, but previously I got same data four times.